# Javascript - setTimeout/setInterval execute countdown before the function

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I have a timer which triggers a function each 3 seconds using setTimeout or setInterval. The point is that I need to execute the countdown before the function instead of execute the function first and then the timer.

This is the code:

```
var timer;

document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('mousedown', function (){
    timer = setInterval(alert("Ey, release the button!"), 3000);
});
```

And this should be the order of actions:

1. Click and hold the button.
2. Start the countdown ...3, 2, 1...
3. Trigger the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like

```
var timer;

   document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('mousedown', function (){
     timer = setTimeout(function(){
       alert("Ey, release the button!");
     }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Errm.. what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is that the `alert`-call is wrapped in a function in this code so it will be passed as a callback. In the OPs code it's not so it will be evaluated and then the result from `alert` will be passed on to `setInterval` which would be useless.

Comment: You have to pass a callback inside setInterval function as first argument which is then called after 3000 milliseconds but you executed the statement there.

Comment: This will alerts every 3 seconds not once.

Comment: @mortezaT The whole idea was to tell how to call the alert. However I modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could trigger another function at the end of the timer. Since you only need to call it once.. You could just use **setTimeout**

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('mousedown', function (){
    alert("Ey, release the button!")
    setTimeout(fireMe, 3000);
});

function fireMe() {
    // Boom
}
```

You might also want to add **clearTimeout** on mouseup event.